# jQuery ajax works but not native JS ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code:

**Controller**

```
def some_method
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render js: "alert();" }
 end
end
```

**JS**

This executes alert();

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: url
});
```

This doesn't executes alert();

```
var xhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhttp.send();
```

What is so different in jQuery than plain JavaScript?

**Note**:

1> Both the requests fire the AJAX. But, only jQuery request executes the JS code, but not native JS AJAX.

2> I have already compared, **Request** and **Response** headers for both types of requests. But, I don't find any difference.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @Walk 1.8.3. But, how does that matter?

Comment: I believe it's a bug in jQuery 1.x and 2.x, it shouldn't be executed immediately in 3.x. Check this page https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432 I guess you'll have to `eval` result to achieve same functionality.

Comment: `only jQuery request executes the JS code` - the problem is, it shouldn't. what `content-type` header is returned in the response

Comment: @JaromandaX It's `Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8` for both the cases

Comment: hmm, wonder if jquery does something stupid with the response then, because you **don't** want AJAX to arbitrarily execute - that's not what AJAX is about

Comment: @Walk - `I guess you'll have to eval result` - or create a script tag and shove the response into it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I digged inside `jQuery.ajax` code and found that `jQuery.ajax` also executes **done** within it's code that evaluates the response. So, in native JS we can evaluate the response, like:

```
var xhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState > 3 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      eval(xhttp.responseText); // This line does the trick
    }
  };
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhttp.send();
```